# Django REST RetrieveAPIView combining querysets

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a queryset which combines two query results, namely from Category and Course. Every Course has a Category foreign key. Is there a way to add the respective Courses to each Category?

Example:

```
{
    "id": 61,
    "name": "fgfdf",
    "courses": 
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category": 61,
            "title": "mytitle"
            "active": true
        },
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

**Url**

```
path('dict/<pk>/', DictView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

**Models**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

class Course(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**View**

This is what I imagined but it's obviously incorrect, I've done some research but I couldn't find what I needed.

```
class DictView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Category.objects.all()
        courses = list(Course.objects.filter(category=pk))
        queryset['courses'] = courses;
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is defining serializers like this:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = CourseSerializer(source='course_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"
```

Then, you don't need to override `get_queryset` anymore.

If you wish to apply filters for courses, say you only want active courses, you can do the following:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_courses(self, obj):
        active_courses = obj.course_set.filter(active=True)
        return CourseSerializer(active_courset, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but I would also like to filter the courses. For example courses where active=True. Could you provide an example for that?

Comment: @SJ19 Updated my answer for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last question, do you maybe have an idea how to get the logged in user.pk in get_courses? (to use it in filter) For example in views.get_queryset you can use "self.request.user.pk".

Comment: @SJ19 You can use `self.context['request'].user` to access requesting user in serializer.